# How do I update/rename the API name for a process builder?

Tags: process-builder

How do I update/rename the API name for a process builder?

I have create a notification process through process builder.  Once I have activate and tested, and realized that I had the name incorrect. However I have not been able to change it. Where can I make this update?

Answer (score 7):

While you can change the Name of the Process, but you cannot change the API Name of the process once it is created. If you need to change the API name, you will need to deactivate the current one, clone it as a new process and provide a new API name. There are ideas on to allow this feature, but not available yet.

Refer to the screenshot below which states considerations on API Name on the help text. It reads:

> Used by the API and managed packages, this name must be unique across all processes and flows. **Once saved, the API name can't be changed for the process**. Each component within the process has an automatically generated API name based on this one for the process.

[image]

Idea link:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000oMabAAE